# SQLite database is locked even while trying to queue data and write using only one thread at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, concurrency, task

I know that the message `SQLite error (5): database is locked` means there is some concurrent writing to the database.
But here I'm trying to queue all data (from multiple threads) into a `ConcurrentQueue` and lock the code processing that queue to ensure that only one thread works on the queue which means only one thread writes to the database at a time.

The code is just like this:

```
public class DataService {
     readonly ConcurrentQueue<Item> _cacheQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Item>();
     public void SaveItem(Item item) {
         _cacheQueue.Enqueue(item);
         _processQueue();
     }
     void _saveItemCore(Item item){
         //logic here to save the item (with write access to the SQLite database)
     }
     bool _isProcessingQueue;
     object _lo = new object();
     void _processQueue(){
        lock(_lo){
            if(_isProcessingQueue) return;
            _isProcessingQueue = true;
            while(_cacheQueue.Count > 0){
                Item e;
                if(_cacheQueue.TryDequeue(out e)){
                     _saveItemCore(e);
                }
            }
            _isProcessingQueue = false;
        }
     }
}
```

I have multiple threads (each corresponding to a `Task.Run`). All threads call the method `SaveItem` concurrently.

But as you can see my code seems not working, I can still see the message `SQLite error (5): database is locked`. What could be wrong here?

**NOTE:** my threads also perform reading to the database, so if the db is currently being written to by one thread, will it lock the reading by another thread? If this is the case, then this could explain my problem.

**UPDATE**: I've also tried enabling the WAL journal mode by modifying the connection string like this:

```
data source=app.db;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
```

but I can still see the message `SQLite error (5): database is locked`. I'm not so sure if this is OK, whether the reading is successful or not.

Comment: maybe your DB is locked, for good. Can you connect to it and try a command?

Comment: @Pixou of course it is locked but not always, sometimes it prints that message in the output window. And I know that it is locked because of my threads themselves, such as while a thread is writing to the db, another thread reading the db will be locked. And I'm asking for a solution for this, looks like even the **journal_mode** of `WAL` is still not working perfectly.